# Python - arguments to dictionary

Tags: python, search

I am tuning my Python script which is taking about 13 seconds of 21 seconds just to search a string inside an array of arrays.

My script accepts any number of csv files as arguments and will read a column of csv file to array inside an parent array. This array will then be used for checking if a member exists in a array as below:

```
intArray = -1
for childlist in MasterArray:
    intArray += 1
    if 'a' in childlist:
        print(intArray)
        break
```

Can you please advise how do I handle this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to handle this case"? What is the problem with the code you have shown? What would you like it to do differently?

Comment: Granted, this is an example case; but what is the end goal?  Meaning, why are you searching through the array for a character?  I ask to prompt the thought that there might be a different/better way to structure the data.

Comment: i have a source data file with multiple members and value. now i have to find the category of each member. each csv which we are passing as parameter is a category and its members under it. I want to tune the search functionality. But not sure how to create dictionary dynamically for each source category and search through for each member